# using Linux shell script to edit and rename a file

Tags: vim, vi, ex, ed

I am trying to execute a command using Vi or ex to edit a file by deleting the first five lines, replace `x` with `y`, remove extra spaces at the end of each line but retain the carraige returns, and remove the last eight lines of the file, then rename the file into a shell script and run the new script from the current script.

This will be something that is scheduled in cron. I have been looking for a simple way to do it using the command line or a Vim script or something.

Any ideas? The format of the input file does not change, just the amount of lines, so I can't specify the line numbers for the last eight lines.

Comment: You realize that sounds like a bad idea, right? Maybe you really do need to do what you've described, but it sounds *extremely* fragile, and debugging the process you've described would be very un-fun.

Comment: scripting `ex` is possible, using a HERE document. Not all `ex`s respond exactly the same, you'll need to experiment, and if you change OS it may not work without tinkering. Not fun and fragile as mentioned above. good luck.

Comment: Sometimes these obstacle course questions turn out to be homework.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. this is what i got to work. ex -c "%s/No Database Reference                                              /rm -f /g" -c "1,5 d" -c $ -c d -c wq /home/gisadmin/DoDRM.sh
ex -c $ -c d -c d -c d -c wq /home/gisadmin/DoDRM.sh
ex -c $ -c d -c d -c d -c wq /home/gisadmin/DoDRM.sh

Answer (score 1):

You actually have about half a dozen questions here. Here's an answer for the first five which are probably the ones you'll have the most difficulty solving:

```
sed -e ':label' -n -e '1d' -e 's/x/y/g' -e 's/[ \t]*$//g' -e '1,9!{P;N;D};N;b label' file.txt > script.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

Vi is an interactive editor.  You probably don't want to use it for something that'll be run by cron.  Also, I agree with the comments saying this is probably a bad idea.  Be that as it may:

```
printf 'one\ntwo\nthree\nfour\nfive\necho x \n1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n' \
| sed '1,5d;s/  *$//;s/x/y/' \
| tail -r | sed 1,8d | tail -r \
| sh
```

Our first sed script does most of the work.  We reverse the lines with `tail -r`, then delete the first 8 lines, then reverse again.  That trims off the last 8 lines.

Note that on Linux systems (or any with GNU coreutils), you may also have a `tac` command which reverse lines, but `tail -r` is more portable.

Also, the final `| sh` simply runs the output.  If you REALLY want to save this as a script, you can do that by redirecting the output to a file ... but I'll leave at least that to your imagination.  Can't do all your scripting for you, can we?!  :-)

Answer (score 0):

To edit a file by a script, you could use `ed`  (even if it hard to learn or remember).

You could also use some scripting language (Python, Perl, AWK, Ruby) to achieve your goal.